# There have any method to delete multiple items permanently in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have multiple soft deleted items. And I need to delete these items permanently. When I try to delete using these methods **Product::destroy($id);** or **Product::('id', $ids)->delete();** it's not working.

Please can give me any solution?
Thlans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can permanently delete a soft deleted model with `forceDelete`:

```
$product->forceDelete();
```

Or an entire collection:

```
Product::withTrashed()->find($ids)->each(function ($product, $key) {
    $product->forceDelete();
});
```

Comment: This method for singe item delete and I have Tried.

Comment: But I need to delete multiple row

Comment: If you don't need to record model events. I reckon this query could work too: Product::withTrashed()->detele($idsArray);

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for it is :

```
Product::whereIn('id',[111,112,113,115])->forceDelete();
```